# Auto adjust div margin Top Dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have a loop of div with different height based on its content. Is there a way to auto adjust margin top of the next div if the one above it has smaller height than the div beside it? My structure is like this.

[image]

I have two columns and wanted to adjust the test3 div to remove the space. I tried using flex but still it doesn't work. This is my code

```
<div style="height:auto;display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;align-content: flex-start;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: auto; background:red;align-self: baseline;">
        TEST1
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: auto; background:red;align-self: baseline;">
        TEST2<br>
        TEST2
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: auto; background:red;align-self: baseline;">
        TEST3<br>
        TEST3<br>
        TEST3
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; height: auto; background:red;align-self: baseline;">
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4
    </div>
</div>
```

In the example, I manually added the div and its content but originally it was created in a loop. Please help me on this. Thank You

Comment: No, there is no way to _automatically_ do that. This is just not how _rows_ work.

Comment: Yes, make sense. I understand @CBroe . Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case column 3 now starts where column 2 ends.

Is it possible for you to use float?
In that case try float:left for column 1 and 3. And float:right for column 2 and 4.

EDIT:
Try this. Note the `float:left` in the wrapped div.

```
<div style="height:auto; width:800px; float:left">
    <div style="width: 400px; float:left; background:red;">
        TEST1
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; float:right; background:yellow;">
        TEST2<br>
        TEST2
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; float:left; background:green;">
        TEST3<br>
        TEST3<br>
        TEST3
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; float:right; background:blue;">
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, div are created using loop and I may not know how many div will be created. I tried using float but it still have same result.

Comment: @Yhajiks, If you need help with the loop, just let me know

Comment: Thank You @LvO. It gives me now an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the align-self, if you want two columns and you know each column is about 400px you make the container div of 800px and they will fit perfectly as the code below

```css
.container {
   width: 800px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-content: flex-start;
  }
  
.row {
   width: 400px;
   height: auto;
   background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        TEST1
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        TEST2<br>
        TEST2
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        TEST3<br>
        TEST3<br>
        TEST3
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4<br>
        TEST4
    </div>
</div>
```

If you also want rows not to be merged use `margin` in the row css as you want.

By the way I add you a FlexBox tutorial that is so helpful because you can see what class you can add to the container or the rows.

[Flex Box Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope it helps you!! :)

Comment: Thank You for answering, but I don't want to do it this way. It's like test1 div has different height to test2 div, and with that empty space below test1 div, I want to put the test3 div in there. @GonzaloPani

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use flexboxes you will need 2 sub-containers:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="testContainer">
    <div> TEST 1 </div>
    <div> TEST 3 <br> TEST 3 <br> TEST 3 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="testContainer">
    <div> TEST 2 <br> TEST 2 </div>
    <div> TEST 4 <br> TEST 4 <br> TEST 4 <br> TEST 4 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .mainContainer { display: flex; }
  .testContainer { display:flex; flex-direction: column; }
</style>
```

In your loop you will just need a `column` variable that determine the target column for the data:

```js
// JS
var data = [
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 2],
  [ 3, 3, 3 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4]
]
var columns = document.querySelectorAll("#container div")
var numColumn = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var column = columns[numColumn];
  var testHTML = "" + (column.innerHTML != '' ? '<br>' : '');
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
    testHTML += "TEST " + (i+1);
    if (j < data[i].length-1) testHTML += "<br>";
  }
  column.innerHTML += testHTML
  numColumn = ++numColumn % 2;
}
```

```css
/* CSS */
.mainContainer { display: flex;}
.testContainer { display:flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="mainContainer" id="container">
  <div class="testContainer"></div>
  <div class="testContainer"></div>
</div>
```